# RegistrationManager: 405: Method Not Allowed after initialization

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

After I initialized the SDK in my applications onCreate I am getting the following logs and can't receive any push messages sent.

```
D/JobIntentService: Completing work: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c$f$a@ab38b12
D/JobIntentService: Done processing work!
V/RequestManager: REGISTRATION request took 1677ms with code: 405
D/RegistrationManager: 405: Method Not Allowed
V/RequestManager: SYNC request took 422ms with code: 405
D/AlarmScheduler: No pending REGISTRATION Alarm. Creating one ...
D/AlarmScheduler: Setting the REGISTRATION Alarm Flag ...
V/AlarmScheduler: REGISTRATION Alarm scheduled to wake at 2020-11-11T14:02:52.860Z.
D/AlarmScheduler: SYNC Send Pending ... will send at 2020-11-11T14:18:38.390Z
E/i: Sync route request failed with message: Method Not Allowed - Sdk Version: 7.2.0
```

Comment: Please open a support request through your account manager.

Answer (score 2):

Was a mistake on my side. The forgot to change the `marketingCloudServerUrl` when the server team updated it.